# POST request works in Postman but gives Bad Request in js code

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, localhost, postman, http-status-code-400

I'm hosting some python code on a local server with Flask and I'm trying to send a POST request with an image. Using Postman, everything works fine:[image]

There are no extra headers other than Content-Type (no Authorization).

The same request inside a javascript function returns 400 (Bad Request).

```
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("image", "image089.png");

    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/croprect",
      "method": "POST",
      "processData": false,
      "contentType": false,
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
      "data": form
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

The file "image089.png" is in the same directory as the script. This function is wrapped by a click event and assigned to a button. The web application is hosted locally in a Tomcat server. I'm not sure what other information would be useful.

I found plenty of similar questions but most are unanswered..

EDIT: Using XHR syntax also doesn't work:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    });

    xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/croprect");

    xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: Removing the headers property entirely didn't work. Still getting bad request both in jQuery and XHR.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending to the `FormData` object correctly. Currently you are setting the value of `image` to a string. Rather, you'll need to instruct `FormData` to attach the file contents with a name contained in that string:

> There are two versions of this method: a two and a three parameter
>   version:
>
> `1| formData.append(name, value); 
>   2| formData.append(name, value, filename);`

**Change**

```
form.append("image", "image089.png");
```

**To**

```
form.append("image", BlobWithYourImage, "image089.png");
```

Also, heed this warning:

> If you specify a Blob as the data to append to the FormData object,
>   the filename that will be reported to the server in the
>   "Content-Disposition" header used to vary from browser to browser.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)